# As part of JMeter web driver (Selenium scripts) integration with Azure Pipeline and how can I add plugin manager in Azure Pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, jmeter, cicd, jmeter-plugins

As part of JMeter web driver (Selenium scripts) integration with Azure Pipeline and how can I add plugin manager in Azure Pipeline

Someone suggested this link https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#Add-Your-Plugin-or-Repository but still I didn't get so can anyone suggest me the step by steps procedure on Azure Pipeline please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be correct, you just made a typo

It should be

```
jpgc-webdriver
```

and you have

```
jpgc -webdriver
```

Remove this whitespace and it should be successful.

---

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)